# getForm: retry connection upon error

Tags: r

For a web scraping project I am making frequent requests on a particular site. Sometimes the connection times out with an error and I would like for it to retry instead of erroring out. I've written out the code below for it to keep trying, but I don't think it works because I still error out.

```
url = "www.google.com"
while(true){
   withRestarts(tryCatch(
       sourcecode <- getForm(urls[n]),
       finally = Sys.sleep(2), 
       abort = function(){})
}
```

> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to
>   host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it after experimenting:

```
while(length(sourcecode.ad) == 0){
      try({
        sourcecode <- getForm(urls[n])
        print(urls[n])
        Sys.sleep(1) 
      })
    }
```

Try() will allow a continuation after an error occurs. Combined with the loop, it will keep retrying.